# JSON serialize/deserialize to dictionary containing dictionaries

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I am working on a project implementing a DotSpatial tab/ribbon application. Each tab is a plugin. When the project is saved, a RaiseSaveRequest event handler creates a dictionary that is passed to each plugin's projectSavedListener through e. Then within the listener, e.dictPackedStates.adds(pluginName, PackState()), which goes to each plugin's PackState(), packes itself up into a dictionary. So, the whole application's state is saved in the dictPackedStates dictionary as  of pluginName, dictionary of each plugin.

I am using JSON.NET to serialize/deserialize the file when it's saved/opened.I think my save is working fine.

```
Dictionary<string, object> pluginStates = new Dictionary<string, object>();
signaller.RaiseSaveRequest(pluginStates);

//JSON
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pluginStates);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strPathName); 
sw.Write(json);
sw.Close();
```

My sw.Write(json); seems to be writing the JSON to the file. I can open the file and see it all. Then in my open, I have:

```
Dictionary<string, object> pluginStates = new Dictionary<string, object>();

//JSON
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fullName);
string json = sr.ReadToEnd();
pluginStates = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
sr.Close();

signaller.UnpackProjectState(pluginStates);
```

My pluginStates are not the same way as they were before they were serialized. When they get saved, the dictionary looks like: (wanted to have a pic here of what it looks like, cant figure out how)..

```
pluginStates  Count=5, 
(hit plus, 1st entry) [0] {[Project Manager, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.String,System.Object]]}
(hit plus on that entry) Key  "Project Manager" Value  Count =1
(hit plus on value) [0]  {[ProjectName, test5.vbpx]}
```

Then in the open, it's getting in the PluginStates that the signaller.UnpackProjectState sends off is:

```
pluginStates  Count=5 
(hit plus, 1st entry)  [0] {[Project Manager, { "ProjectName": "test5.vbpx"}]}
(hit plus)  Key  "Project Manager"  Value  { "ProjectName": "test5.vbpx"}
(hit plus on value) .. first thing is base {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Jcontainer}
```

This leads to an error in the first plugin's UnpackState(object objPackedState). The object sent is the value { "ProjectName": "test5.vbpx"} instead of the 1st item in the saved dictionary above {[Project Manager, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.String,System.Object]]}.

I hope that explained enough of my issue. Any suggestions on how to get the deserializeObject to get the dictionary back in the correct format?
Thanks so much!!

Comment: I think I'm on the right path to fixing the problem. The main dictionary that has the key:pluginName & value:packedDictionary was set to be a dictionary<string,object>. I changed this to be a dictionary<string, dictionary<string,object>. Now, I'm getting an error saying: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'System.Data.DataTable' in the first plugin where I'm trying to repopulate the its state like this: this.dt = (DataTable)dictPluginState["DT"]; I have dictionary coming into the UnpackState.. Unpack(dictionary<string,object> dictPluginState. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sort of fixed the problem (and then found my next problem..which I will add as a separate question). I changed the pluginStates dictionary that holds all the plugin's packed states from `Dictionary<string, object>` to `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>` which made the saved pluginStates (before serializing) and opened pluginStates (after deserializing) the same. until I dig down to the actual Plugin's Unpack Method, which isn't being deserialized correctly.